# Samsung OTA Update is published but the update is not yet available on my phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, updates, samsung, ota-update

I have a Samsung phone and would like to update it because there already is an update.   However when I try to update my phone it says I already have the latest update. How can I update my phone?

Answer (score 1):

The time that it takes to receive the update on your phone can take some time because it will vary per device.
If **Samsung** will let everyone update their phone at the **same time** when the update is available then their servers will **crash** because everyone is downloading the update at the same time.
To solve this problem you can update your phone with **Samsung Kies**. Just follow the steps below:

> **Note:** This will require a PC with  **Windows** or **Mac**.

1. Download **Samsung Kies** from their official website here: [Samsung Kies Download](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/#_download_anchor)
2. Now install **Samsung Kies**
3. When finished installing, connect your phone to your PC with an USB cable.
4. Wait till the device is recognized by **Samsung Kies**.
5. Now **Samsung Kies** should give a notification that there is an **OTA** update available.
6. Do not disconnect your phone while it is installing the update!
7. Enjoy your updated Samsung phone.

Comment: +1, but my question is: does Samsung hosts the OTA update at some server from where I can download it and flash it via Recovery? Or, may be some well trusted source hosts it. Are you aware of such?

Comment: @Firelord Samsung downloads it in a `tar.md5` and that file will be flashed in **download mode** and not **recovery mode**

Comment: @Firelord the official way is to do it with **Kies**, but you can also manually flash the OTA with **Odin** but that will void your warranty. If you are going to flash it with Odin then you should download the ROM here: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares